# Which permission or Setting required for allowing facility to user to login from any iP Range in Salesforce Org?

Tags: administration, user-management

I created a new org where I can see a button Allow All Ranges(!).

[image: Allow All Ranges]

But for the orgs that I am working earlier or in the recent org that I created now does not have this feature, can somebody please advise how to enable this feature in salesforce org.

Comment: Add `0.0.0.0` for `Start IP Address` and `End IP Address` should be `255.255.255.255` this will allow to login from any IP range. Try this, i did this on the Profile level

Comment: Are you sure you haven't got a browser plugin enabled that does that? I know there is a [similar one for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whitelist-all-ips-for-sal/nnlnikmkkbpgioojghgojoejgcheilic) that does the same.

Comment: I don't have this plug in however if this would have been from browser plugin then it would have shown for all that orgs that I am logging into using chrome, it just show for one org.

Comment: Let me check one more time for all the chrome extensions that I have

Comment: @RobinDeBondt Thank you so much for pointing that, I tried disabling all the chrome extensions and started enabling chrome extensions one by one and checked by refreshing NetWork Access page, it is becuase of this chrome extension Apex Debugger
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apex-debugger/mpckkbblhbfngaininanfjpdfjhbncjo?hl=en

Comment: @NachiketDeshpande I've written it down as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a native Salesforce functionality. You have a [Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apex-debugger/mpckkbblhbfngaininanfjpdfjhbncjo?hl=en) enabled that makes this button show up.

Answer (score 2):

Add `0.0.0.0` for `Start IP Address` and `End IP Address` should be `255.255.255.255` this will allow to login from any IP range.

[image]

Comment: I have found that some org will balk about that being an invalid range and others work fine

Answer (score 1):

Login IP ranges are used to prevent user logging from IP address which is not known to Salesforce. Specifying range of IP addresses between various classes of IP addresses can improve security level of your application.

If you don't want any restriction then simply go to respective profile -> Login IP Ranges and put start range as `0,0,0,0` and end range as `255,255,255,255`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not getting that button "Allow All ranges" how to enable that? Is it a new feature because I have that enabled in one org while in other orgs I can not see that why ?!

Comment: @NachiketDeshpande I think version of that org is older one. I also cannot find that button in my developer org.

Comment: I created that org which has this feature enabled few days before ,however after that when I am creating any new org I can not find that, that is why getting surprised ! neither I can find any documentation related to it.

Comment: @NachiketDeshpande I also could not find any documentation about it. RobinDeBondt has highlighted about the chrome extension. Please see if you have that.

Comment: it is becuase of this chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apex-debugger/mpckkbblhbfngaininanfjpdfjhbncjo?hl=en
I got surprise because I didn't saw that button in the other orgs that I am logging into

Comment: @NachiketDeshpande That's great. You got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The original way in which we could enable all trusted IPs has gone the way of the dodo ever since Salesforce removed the ability to run javascript on homepage components. However, now there’s a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apex-debugger/mpckkbblhbfngaininanfjpdfjhbncjo?hl=en) to accomplish this same functionality, please use that!